# Media Foundation API and ID3 tag in C++

Tags: c++, mp3, id3, ms-media-foundation

I am writing a utility that will encode uncompressed audio to MP3. I am using C++ and the media foundation API, which is really slick at encoding to MP3. But I need to ensure the ID3 tag is at the beginning of the file. I am writing the ID3 tag data using ID3Lib and then I am invoking the MF API to handle the encoding to MP3. In doing so, the encoding to MP3 is basically starting at the beginning of the file and it is overwriting the ID3 tag data in the file.

Is there any way to encode via the media foundation API and have it NOT overwrite the existing ID3 data?

If not, is there any way to write the ID3 data using the MF API? I can find articles that describe getting the metadata but little to nothing on writing the metadata.

Answer (score 0):

A possible way would be to use the sink writer.

Call [MFCreateFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms696166(v=vs.85).aspx) to open your id3 tagged file.
You Receive a pointer to the IMFByteStream interface.

Call Seek or SetCurrentPosition on the IMFByteStream interface to seek at the end of the file (After ID3 tag data).

Call [MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd388105(v=vs.85).aspx) and pass the pointer of the IMFByteStream, use NULL for the output url.

Do the transcode process.

I didn't try this solution, so perhaps the sinkwriter will seek at the beginnig of the file. If so, you can try to implement your own IMFByteStream interface to avoid this case.